# Is Moonlight (first movement) suitable for grade 7?

Tags: piano, exam-grades, abrsm

Can I play Sonata No. 14 “Moonlight” (first movement) by L. Van Beethoven for ABRSM digital Performance Grade 7 for piano as my own choice?

As per [Performance Grades - FAQs](https://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/performancegrades/faq/):

> For the exam candidates choose and perform four pieces/songs, presented as a continuous programme: at least three pieces from our existing syllabus (one from each list) and one piece of the candidate’s own choice. The own-choice piece can be another item from the syllabus at the same grade or from any other published source, **as long as the level of difficulty is the same**.

So I mean whether it's suitable in terms of similar level of difficulty for that grade.

[image: Does Sonata No. 14 “Moonlight” (first movement) by L. Van Beethoven]

Comment: You can check here: https://us.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/piano-exams/piano-grade-7/

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

The first movement of the Moonlight sonata has not been (publicly) graded by ABRSM, but the consensus puts it around grade 6, with grade 7 as a "maybe". I would err on the side of Grade 6, but if played with exceptional musicality, it would likely be acceptable in a grade 7 exam.

**I strongly recommend contacting ABRSM (or your local ABRSM coordinator) to ask if that piece is acceptable.**

#### Discussion

Jane Magrath — whose book *The Pianist's Guide to Standard Teaching and Performance Literature* uses her own grading system — places the Moonlight sonata as Level 10, but that's the *entire* sonata, including the far more difficult third movement.

However, comparing her grades on other ABRSM Grade 7 pieces, the Chopin Mazurka Op. 68, no. 2 she places at Level 9. Likewise, Moszkowski's "Calme du soir" (op. 94, no. 2) she places at level 8–9; Mendelssohn's "Song without Words" (Op. 19, no. 1) at level 9; Schumann's "Kind im Einschlummern" (Op. 15, no. 12) at level 9; and Debussy's "The Little Shepherd (*Children's Corner*, no. 5) at Level 8.

Magrath's grading system is her own and distinct from the ABRSM's system; however, the two bear reasonable consistency with each other. That is, harder pieces get higher grades; easier ones get lower grades; and where there are differences, the tend to be only by one grade level.

On the other hand, in the opinion of The Piano Bubble ([What Piano Grade is Beethoven’s Moonlight Sonata 1st Movement?](https://pianobubble.com/what-piano-grade-is-beethovens-moonlight-sonata-1st-movement/)), it's a Grade 6 piece.

> Beethoven’s Moonlight Sonata 1st movement would be approximately grade 6 level if you are only concerned with playing the notes correctly.

However, the author allows that

> to do it justice, the technical skill required to play this movement musically makes it diploma standard.

Discussion on the ABRSM forum (Moonlight Sonata By Beethoven ([what Grade Level?](https://forums.abrsm.org/index.php?showtopic=19490)) also suggests the piece would be Grade 6, or even Grade 5. The thread [Beethovens "moonlight" Sonata](https://forums.abrsm.org/index.php?showtopic=658) also suggests Grades 5 or 6.

On Quora, [What grade would the Moonlight Sonata 1st and 2nd movement be?](https://www.quora.com/What-grade-would-the-Moonlight-Sonata-1st-and-2nd-movement-be) suggests Grade 6 or 7; and [What piano grade is Moonlight Sonata?](https://www.quora.com/What-piano-grade-is-Moonlight-Sonata) places the first movement at Grade 7 or 8.

On PianoWorld, [What Grade are these pieces?](http://forum.pianoworld.com/ubbthreads.php/topics/1620685/What_Grade_are_these_pieces.html) guesses at Grade 5. PianoForum guesses everything from Grade 5 up to Grade 9.

Comment: I mean the [digital exam](https://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/performancegrades/faq/) which require 4 pieces. _For the exam candidates choose and perform four pieces/songs._

Comment: @Aida My mistake. Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer. Please let me know if it's sufficient to your needs.